# Rails syntax Passing POST parameters from a form to a controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, forms, parameters, controller

I'm new to Rails (and fairly new to programming in general) and I am building a web app for myself as a way to learn.  Right now I am modifying scaffolded forms and such.

My question is with the "create" method in one of my controllers. There are two entities I am concerned with:  the User table and the Habit table.  I created a dropdown box in the _form partial for the Habit views to allow a person to select a user from a list of all available when creating a habit as below

```
<%= collection_select  :user, :id, @users, :id, :first_name %>
```

The habit controller, of course, has

```
def new
  @users = User.all
  ...    
end
```

This works fine, and when the form submits it posts two hashes of parameters :habit and :user. Now, when I want to process the form input in the create method, I'm not sure how to use the syntax correctly and assign the user_id to the newly create habit.  What I WANT to do is something like this

```
def create
   @habit = Habit.new(params[:habit], params[:user])
end
```

This, of course, is improper syntax.

```
def create
   @habit = Habit.new(params[:habit])
end
```

assigns the params from the :habit hash correctly, but then the user_id is left unset.

What works is the following, but the code is very lengthy, assigning each value manually.

```
def create
    @habit = Habit.new(:user_id => params[:user][:id], 
                   :description => params[:habit][:description], 
                   :habit_method => params[:habit][:habit_method], 
                  :time_reqd => params[:habit][:time_reqd],
                  :will_reqd => params[:habit][:will_reqd],
                  :active => params[:habit][:active])

end
```

So my question is, when dealing with a form that posts data in multiple hashes, what is the proper way to pass those parameters into some method in a controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is, when dealing with a form that posts data in multiple hashes, what is the proper way to pass those parameters into some method in a controller?

Instead of saying `Habit.new( <lots of stuff> )`, just use `Habit.new(params[:habit])`. Rails will try to assign each key in the hash (in this case, the `params[:habit]` hash's keys) to a matching value on the object.

Thus, if params[:habit] has a `:description` key, it will be assigned to a field called `description` on your model. This is called *mass assignment* and is quite handy.

Now you can just do:

```
@habit = Habit.new(params[:habit])
@habit.user_id = params[:user][:id]
```

You may want to read the **[RoR Getting Started Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)**, like **[this section](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-new-posts)**, for more similarly handy features of Rails.

Comment: ah, ok.  so the mass assignment is kind of a shortcut.  That makes sense. One more syntax question:  If the :user hash had multiple keys (in the previous example it only has one), will this mass assign that hash `@habit = params[:user]`?  In other words, can you use mass assignment on an existing object?  Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: No; `@habit = params[:user]` makes a copy of the `params[:user]` object (which is a hash), so all you did was overwrite `@habit` with that. You can do `@habit.attributes = <some hash>`, though.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<%= collection_select  :user, :id, @users, :id, :first_name %>
```

To

```
<%= collection_select  :habit, :user_id, @users, :id, :first_name %>
```

The existing scaffold code should just work after that

Alternate

```
<%= f.select :user_id, @users, :id, :first_name %>
```

Comment: Thanks! Those examples help me understand the arguments for select, collection select, etc.